# How to activate a button when selecting several mat-checkbox and deactivate it only when nothing is selected? (Angular material)

Tags: angular, typescript, button, checkbox, angular-material

I'm making a table using Angular Material. Inside the table I have data, which is added from a DB that I have created in JAVA. The checkboxes are created depending on the number of rows (data) that are in the DB. The idea is that the button to send this data to another table MUST BE disabled and it **MUST ONLY BE ENABLED** when there is at least 1 active checkbox, if there is no active checkbox the button must be disabled.

The problem is that when I deselect 1 checkbox the button is disabled, regardless of whether the other checkboxes are active.

**HTML**

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="buttonDisable" (click)="procesarClic()">Enviar</button>

<ng-container matColumnDef="seleccionVarios">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef><label class="tituloTabla-verdoso text-center"> CHECKBOX </label></mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <mat-checkbox #checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                        (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(element) : null; changeCheck($event)"
                                        [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)">
               </mat-checkbox>
             </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**TypeScript**

```
export class PaginaPrincipal implements OnInit {
    buttonDisable: boolean = true;

changeCheck(event){
    this.buttonDisable = !event.checked;
  }
```

Comment: **Edit:** The error that came up was because, starting up, I had nothing selected so I can't get an attribute of something that doesn't exist, so I made a check in the TS and that's it! Thank you very much for your help @Eliseo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want that Angular make it for you, you only need a FormArray and a custom validator.

If your define

```
checked:FormArray
```

When you create the dataSource (*), e.g. in ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

    this.checked = new FormArray(
      this.dataSource.map((x) => new FormControl()),
      this.someChecked()
    );
  }
```

You need two auxiliars function:

```
  //A custom Validator
  someChecked() {
    return (form: AbstractControl) => {
      return form.value.find((x) => x)
        ? null
        : { error: 'almost one must be select' };
    };
  }

//and an auxiliar "getter"
checkedAt(index:number){
    return this.checked.at(index) as FormControl
}
```

You can use a cell like

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="seleccionVarios">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>...</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index">
    <mat-checkbox [formControl]="checkedAt(i)"> </mat-checkbox>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

And your button:

```
<button mat-button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="checked.errors">
submit
</button>
```

And.. voilá! Futhermore you can get the "selected" elements like

```
submit()
{
    const selected=this.dataSource.filter((_,index)=>this.checked.value[index])
    console.log(selected)
}
```

see a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tnhk9?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

(*)Be carefull, in the example the dataSource is an array, if you use a MatTableDataSource you need iterate over datasource.data

```
    this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);

    this.checked = new FormArray(
      this.dataSource.data.map((x) => new FormControl()),
      this.someChecked()
    );

//and in submit
const selected=this.dataSource.data.filter(
              (_,index)=>this.checked.value[index])
```

Comment: Hi Eliseo! Thank you very much for your prompt response, it was very helpful. However, checking the console the following error appears:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')**

As I understand it (and excuse me for the ignorance but I'm new to Angular) the ".errors" that we added to the [disabled] of the button is the same that we put in the TS when we used someChecked( )?

Comment: A [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) as a FormControl or a FormGroup are classes with many properties. One of them is "errors". `errors` can be "null" or an object.when we use [Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms), each change in the "input" it's executed and give value to this property. You can see if write in .html `<pre>{{checked.errors|json}}</pre>. When you write `[disabled]="checked.errors"` is disabled if the formArray has errors or enabled if this variable is null.

Comment: Is like `[disabled]="checked.errors!=null:true:null"` (In angular if a variable is null, when you write `[attribute]`="variable"` not add the attribute

Comment: Thanks Eliseo! So, as I understand it, the validator always shows the error in console if the button is disabled, but would there be a way for this error not to appear?

Comment: I saw the example you sent and the console doesn't show an error. I don't know if it's because I have a different submit ( ) attribute, I can't think of anything else.

`submit() {
    var request = this.selection.selected
    const newTable = this.dialog.open(SomeDialog, {
      width: '400px',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { datosItem:request }
    });    
  }`

I do this so that in the dialog box it shows me the items of the rows that I selected with the checkbox

Comment: I don't know about your "this.selection.selected". In my example I create a variable filtered the "dataSource" using the formArray (BTW, **not** use "var", use `let` if you are going to change the variable or `const`, see [docs](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem with this solution and it is that when changing the page (with the paginator) to see the other rows, the checkboxes don't change, they are still active and in the same position in which they were clicked. If it takes the information from the other rows on the other page but if I have 16 rows and I want to select all of them, I won't be able to. The paginator have a 10 rows, and the other 6 rows are on the other page of the paginator, and it is those rows that I cannot select because when changing the paginator they are already selected.

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="comprobarFilas()" (click)="procesarClic()">Solicitar</button>

<ng-container matColumnDef="seleccionVarios">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef><label class="tituloTabla-verdoso text-center"> CHECKBOX </label></mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index">
                <mat-checkbox #checkbox ((click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(element) : null;"
                                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)"
                                    [formControl]="checkedAt(i)">
               </mat-checkbox>
             </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**TS:**

```
     ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
    
        this.checked = new FormArray (
            this.dataSourceSolicitudNew.data.map((x) => new FormControl()),
            this.someChecked()
          );
      }
    
    someChecked() {
        return (form: AbstractControl) => {
          return form.value.find((x) => x)
            ? null
            : { error: 'almost one must be select' };
        };
      }
    
      checkedAt(index: number) {
        return this.checked.at(index) as FormControl;
      }
    
      comprobarFilas() {
        if(this.checked == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
          return this.checked.errors;
        }
    }

procesarClic() {
    const request = this.selection.selected
    const newTable = this.dialog.open(SolicitudNewDialog, {
      width: '400px',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { datosItem:request }
    });    
  }
```

The "procesarClic()" function opens a dialog popup where I must show the list of the items that I selected. **Thanks for your help!**